# python-daemon and logging: set logging level interactively

Tags: python, logging, python-daemon

I have a python-daemon process that logs to a file via a ThreadedTCPServer (inspired by the cookbook example: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network, as I will have many such processes writing to the same file). I am controlling the spawning of the daemon process using subprocess.Popen from an ipython console, and this is how the application will be run. I am able to successfully write to the log file from both the main ipython process, as well as the daemon process, but I am unable to change the level of both by just simply setting the level of the root logger in ipython. Is this something that should be possible? Or will it require custom functionality to set the logging.level of the daemon separately?

Edit: As requested, here is an attempt to provide a pseudo-code example of what I am trying to achieve. I hope that this is a sufficient description.

daemon_script.py

```
import logging
import daemon 
from other_module import function_to_run_as_daemon

class daemon(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.daemon_name = __name__
         logging.basicConfig()  # <--- required, or I don't get any log messages
         self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.daemon_name)
         self.logger.debug( "Created logger successfully" )

    def run(self):
        with daemon.daemonContext( files_preserve = [self.logger.handlers[0].stream] )
            self.logger.debug( "Daemonised successfully - about to enter function" )
            function_to_run_as_daemon()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = daemon()
    d.run()
```

Then in ipython i would run something like

```
>>> import logging
>>> rootlogger = logging.getLogger()
>>> rootlogger.info( "test" )
INFO:root:"test"
>>> subprocess.Popen( ["python" , "daemon_script.py"] )
DEBUG:__main__:"Created logger successfully"
DEBUG:__main__:"Daemonised successfully - about to enter function"
# now i'm finished debugging and testing, i want to reduce the level for all the loggers by changing the level of the handler
# Note that I also tried changing the level of the root handler, but saw no change
>>> rootlogger.handlers[0].setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> rootlogger.info( "test" )
INFO:root:"test"
>>> print( rootlogger.debug("test") )
None
>>> subprocess.Popen( ["python" , "daemon_script.py"] )
DEBUG:__main__:"Created logger successfully"
DEBUG:__main__:"Daemonised successfully - about to enter function"
```

I think that I may not be approaching this correctly, but, its not clear to me what would work better. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello @bazza1988 and welcome to stackoverflow, without having a concrete, concise and minimal code example that shows off your problem, it's hard to tell what your issue could be.

Comment: @zmo - see edit. I originally hoped that my description would be sufficient to get a qualitative answer. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logger you create in your daemon won't be the same as the logger you made in ipython. You could test this to be sure, by just printing out both logger objects themselves, which will show you their memory addresses.

I think a better pattern would be be that you pass if you want to be in "debug" mode or not, when you run the daemon. In other words, call popen like this:

```
subprocess.Popen( ["python" , "daemon_script.py", "debug"] )
```

It's up to you, you could pass a string meaning "debug mode is on" as above, or you could pass the log level constant that means "debug", e.g.:
    subprocess.Popen( ["python" , "daemon_script.py", "10"] )
(https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#levels)

Then in the daemon's `init` function use argv for example, to get that argument and use it:

```
...
import sys

def __init__(self):
     self.daemon_name = __name__
     logging.basicConfig()  # <--- required, or I don't get any log messages
     log_level = int(sys.argv[1])  # Probably don't actually just blindly convert it without error handling
     self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.daemon_name)
     self.logger.setLevel(log_level)
     ...
```

Comment: thanks! Interesting you mentioned the memory address comparison, I just did that test and, of course, you're correct. However, regarding your solution; the daemon will be a long-running process, in which time the user might wish to change the level without restarting that program. Based on your suggestion, it seems like I would need to implement a method to specifically tell the daemon to change the level - would you agree? (this was what I alluded to in my original question, but I asked the question to see if I was missing something simple)

Comment: @bazza1988 yes for sure exposing a function to change it would work. What I wasn’t sure of is when you needed to change the level. I’m having trouble thinking of a case where you couldn’t simply use info level to log “I started up properly”, if you always want to see that message for example. And then use debug level for abt true debugging things. Then just if you’re having trouble, run at debug level, otherwise run at info level.

Comment: Or if instead of subprocess you made your daemon into a module and imported that in ipython, you’d be able to pas the actual logger around and change its log level the way you were actually thinking of. Then in the daemon you could use some other solution to have IT spawn the workers on other threads or sub processes.